What is the correct status code for a semi-ok response?
I have a client that is asking the server for n elements. The server is asking ChatGPT for n elements, but sometimes ChatGPT returns n-1 or n+1 elements.
Client Code
const count = 3;
var elements = Server.GetElements(count);
for(int i = 0; i < elements.Count; i++)
{
    DoStuff(elements[i]); // Index out of bounds
}

Server Code
var count = ClientRequest.GetCount(); // Client requests 3 elements
List elements = ChatGPT.GetElements(count); // Server returns 4 elements
return elements;

This is going to happen. Ideally, I will fix the server so it always returns the correct number of elements. But ChatGPT is sometimes unpredictable, and I can't invest all my time working out these edge cases.
When the server returns the incorrect number of elements, what should the HTTP Status Code be? Should it still return a 200, or something else?
My normal responses contain a data field, and a meta field with the status code. If this happens, should there be an additional error field? Or would that information belong in the meta field?
Note: I am not asking about paging.

Let me know if this question is better suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ please

Sounds like a paging issue, if you don't have all n items immediately. If you get more than n items, your server can decide which one is "extra" and omit it, or simply report how many items the client is really getting back. ChatGPT is irrelevant; your client is asking your server for information; how your server gets that is an implementation detail that your client will not care about.

When you want to know which site is better suited to ask this question, please compare https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tour and https://stackoverflow.com/tour.   when still in doubt, ask that question at: https://meta.stackexchange.com/

@chepner not a paging issue.  Don't need paging for so few elements.  And if there is an extra element, the server can remove one.  But it cannot add one when it has one short.  But you are right, i could just report the actual number being returned.

I say "paging" because your client is expecting n element, and you either don't have n elements yet or you have more than n elements to return. Your server needs to decide which it is. It's not a "semi-OK" response, unless for some reason it really is an error that there are not exactly n items available immediately.

It sounds like either the client can expect a fuzzy number of results and the server can give a 200 status or the server can refuse to send bad data and send a 500 error. Or you can do something with ChatGPT where you keep generating elements until you have the right amount and send the same number each time to the client.

When you have too few items, you can also use: 206 Partial Content

@Luuk "The HTTP 206 Partial Content successful response status code is sent in response to a range request. The response body contains the requested ranges of data as specified in the Range header of the request." (From the link you sent). I don't think a 206 makes sense in this case. The client isn't using a Range header to make a range request.

@Squiggle: I does make more sense than "semi-ok"......

For partial data, I use both HTTP status code: 200 OK or 206 Partial Content based on the situations.

200 OK: When the server successfully processes the request, even if the data is incomplete, you can use 200. You may consider metadata in the response to indicate that the content is partial:
{
    "elements": [/* partial list */],
    "isPartial": true,
    "message": "This is a incomplete list."
}


206 Partial Content: This is used to indicate partial responses. Can be used with paginated data, byte streams etc.. . For example:
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Content-Range: items 0-49/100

{
    "elements": [/* partial list */],
    "total": 100,
    "returned": 50,
    "message": "Partial response."
}



Which Should You Use?

Use 200 OK if partial data is expected and the client doesn’t need to distinguish it from full data. You can communicate partiality in the response body or headers.
Use 206 Partial Content when it’s important to highlight the response is intentionally incomplete (e.g., a range or pagination).

It comes to the personal choice to use 200 or 206.

206 Partial Content is really supposed to be used in reply to a ranged request, when the client is asking for the data in chunks and the server is saying there's more data available. When the entire content has been sent, even if it's more or less than expected, I'd stick with 200 — but I agree with your statement about 206 under your "Which Should You Use?" heading.
